# How to prevent printing the comma in this enhanced forloop

Tags: java, for-loop

```
for ( int i : array ) {
  System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```

The output keeps printing the comma after the last number of the array.

Comment: How would you solve this with another type of loop?

Comment: use the old school variant with an index?

Comment: what do you want a `string` at the end?

Comment: [The if-then and if-then-else Statements - The Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html)

Comment: Then remove it?

Comment: With some guava joiner no need to use a loop :p

Comment: If that's a `String` array and you're using Java 8, you may as well use `System.out.println(String.join(",", array))` instead of the whole loop. Both readable and solves the comma issue.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to print the *last comma*, e.g. having `[5, 10, 247]` array you want to ptint it out as

```
5, 10, 27
```

you can put it

```
boolean first = true;

for ( int i : array ){
    // If we have items printed add comma before printing the next one
    if (!first)
      System.out.print(", ")

    first = false;

    System.out.print(i);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change it to something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
        if (i == 0) {
          System.out.print(array[i])
        } else { 
          System.out.print("," + array[i])
        }
}
```

So it starts with the comma everytime but the first time.

Comment: Now it should be more clear what i wanted to show..Use a "standard" for-loop.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be something like:

```
System.out.print(
    Arrays.stream(array).mapToObj(Integer::toString).collect(Collectors.joining(", ")));
```

But if you want to do it with an enhanced for loop:

```
String delim = "";
for (int i : array) {
  System.out.print(delim);
  System.out.print(i);
  delim = ", ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use code like this

```
for ( int i; i < array.length; i++){
        if (i !=  array.length-1){
           System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
        } else {
           System.out.print(array[i]);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int count = 0; //flag to know which index you are looping through
    for (int i : array) {
        count++;//increment it every-time
        if (count == 1) { //This is the only time when you do not want the ',' to be printed
            System.out.print(i);
        } else {
            System.out.print(","); //can do (","+i)
            System.out.print(i);
        }
    }
```

Side NOTE: These issues / quirky issues, you need to figure it out as a part of learning!

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which may provide some immediate help.  A proper explanation [would greatly improve](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) its educational value by showing *why* this is a good solution to the problem, and would make it more useful to future readers with similar, but not identical, questions.  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score -1):

comma is printing because of line

```
System.out.print(i +", ");
```

instead if you want a space instead of comma try

```
System.out.print(i+" ");
```

or simply try

```
System.out.println(i);
```

This will change line automatically after printing value of i

Comment: you didn't understand his problem

Answer (score -1):

You could try

```
int arrayLength = array.length;
for ( int i : array){
    if( i == arrayLength - 1 )
        System.out.print(i);
    else
        System.out.print(i + ", ");
}
```

Comment: It will not work, because of `i == arrayLength` strange condition

Comment: The value `i` is *not* the index of the array, it's the actual value.

Comment: This is wrong. `for (int i : array)` makes `i` take the value of the contents of the array. The array might not be an array of ints, and it never takes the value of the position of the array you're currently checking (unless the position and the value are the same).